# Moving div elements stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var move = function() {
    Xpos = Math.round(Math.random() * 95);
    food[num].css('left', Xpos + '%');

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(i);
        var posTop = food[num].offset().top / $(window).height() * 100;

        while(posTop < 80) {
            if(posTop === 80) {
                num++;
                break;
            }

            posTop += 1;
            food[num].css('top', posTop + '%');
            break;
        }
    }, speed);   
}

//Color the circle
circleColor();

move();
}
```

OK so this is my code. It creates a circle(a `<div>` element) on top of the screen and gives it a random x coordinate. Than it puts it in `food[]` array. The entire code starts by clicking the button, but every time I press the button again the circle that was last moving stops, function creates a new one and the new one moves. Is there a way I can make all elements in the array move without depending on each other?

http://jsfiddle.net/yqwjqx31/

I understand why this happens but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You should provide a jsFiddle maybe and you have to provide all relevant code in question

Comment: We'll need some more info. The food array isn't defined. Also, where does the argument "num" come from? It's not defined in the method signature.

Comment: Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/yqwjqx31/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you're using a global variable **num** in setInterval function handler, so its value get modified while using it in new cercle create, secondly you're clearing interval of the last cercle you created before creating a new cercle. It means you're sharing the same interval between all cercles. Use instead an array of intervals just like **var** food =[] and use a temporary variable to prevent the index value modification inside your setInterval handler. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n903x9L2/)

```
    //Interval
    var interval =[];

    var tempNum = num;
    interval[num] = setInterval(function() {
        var posTop = food[tempNum].offset().top / $(window).height() * 100;

        while(posTop < 80) { 
            if(posTop === 80) {

                    break;
            }
            posTop += 1;
            food[tempNum].css('top', posTop + '%');
            break;
        }
    }, speed);
```

Increment your **num** variable

```
    //Color the circle
    circleColor();

    move();
    num++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `move` function is only responsible for moving the last generated `div` via `createCircle`. If you want to move them all till collision, you need to loop through them all and move them accordingly. Or, you can animate them via CSS.

Here is the working version :
http://jsfiddle.net/yqwjqx31/3/

Notice how the `setInterval` callback loops through all the `div` and pushes them down until their height is 80.

```
var move = function () {
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < food.length; ++i) {
                    var posTop = food[i].offset().top / $(window).height() * 100;
                    if (posTop < 80) posTop += 1;
                    food[i].css('top', posTop + '%');
                }
            }, speed);
        }
```